# showing the hidden element after page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

SO i Have an animated form with login and signup on same page with a button toggled login form is shown and vice versa.Now when I submit the form signup form which is accessed by a button the error messages like invalid id or email already taken is shown but the page refreshes and the default form that is login form is shown.

```
 <main>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inner-box">
      <div class="forms-wrap">
        <form action="index.php"  method="POST" autocomplete="off" class="sign-in-form">
          <div class="logo">
      
            <h2>Mero <span>Notes</h2>
          </div>

          <div class="heading">
            <h4>Login to Continue</h4>
          
          </div>
          <?php if(isset($_POST['loginButton'])){
      echo '<p class="echoPar" style=""><i class="fa-solid fa-triangle-exclamation" style="color:red; font-size:11px;"></i> '.$message.'</p>';
      echo'<style>
      .input-field + label {
        font-size: 0.75rem;
        top: -2px;
      }</style>';
   } ?>   
          <div class="actual-form">
            <div class="input-wrap">
              <input 
                type="text"
                minlength="4"
                class="input-field"
                autocomplete="off"name="email"name="password"
                required value="<?= $_POST['email'] ?>"
              />
              <label>Email</label>
            </div>

            <div class="input-wrap">
              <input
                type="password"
                minlength="4"
                class="input-field"
                autocomplete="off"
                required
              />
              <label>Password</label>
            </div>
            <p class="text">
             
             <a href="#"> Forgot Password ?</a> 
           </p>
           <button class="loginButton" id="loginButton" name="loginButton">Log In</button>
            
            
            <h6>Don't Have an Account ?</h6>
            <a href="#" class="toggle">Sign up Here</a>
        
          
          </div>
         
        </form>

        <form id="signUpForm" action="index.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off" class="sign-up-form">
          <div class="logo">
            
            <h2>Mero Notes</h2>
          </div>

          <div class="heading">
            <h4>Get Started</h4>
         
          </div>
          <?php if(isset($_POST['submitBtn'])){
      echo '<p class="echoPar" style=""><i class="fa-solid fa-triangle-exclamation" style="color:red; font-size:11px;"></i> '.$message.'</p>';
      echo "<a href='#signUpForm'></a>";

   echo'<style>
   .input-field + label {
     font-size: 0.75rem;
     top: -2px;
   }</style>';
    }
   ?>          <p id="validationSpan"></p>
          <div class="actual-form">
            <div class="input-wrap">
              <input
                type="text"
                minlength="4"
                class="input-field"
                autocomplete="off"
                name="fullName"
                required
              />
              <label>Name</label>
            </div>

            <div class="input-wrap">
              <input
                type="email"
                class="input-field"
                autocomplete="off" name="email"
                required
              />
              <label>Email</label>
            </div>

            <div class="input-wrap">
              <input
                type="password"
                minlength="4"
                class="input-field"
                autocomplete="off"name="password" id="id_password" minlength="8"  onkeyup="passValidation();"
                required
              />
              <label>Password</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-wrap">
              <input
                type="password"
                class="input-field"
                autocomplete="off"name="conPassword" id="id_conPassword" onkeyup="passValidation();"
                required
              />
              <label>Confirm Password</label>
            </div>

            <button name="submitBtn" type="submit" class="loginButton" type="submit" 
    id="regBtn" onclick="return passValidationAlert()">SignUp </button>

            <h6>Already have an Account ?</h6>
            <a href="#" class="toggle">Sign In Here</a>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

   
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

this is my css for forms

```
  main.sign-up-mode form.sign-in-form {
  opacity: 0;  
   transition: 0.4s;
    pointer-events: none;
    }

       main.sign-up-mode form.sign-up-form {
      opacity: 1;
       pointer-events: all;
      }


      form.sign-up-form {
        transform: translateX(100%);
         transition: 0.8s;
             } 
         main.sign-up-mode form.sign-up-form {
         transform: translateX(0%);
        }
```

any my js to toggle these two forms

```
toggle_btn.forEach((btn) => {
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  main.classList.toggle("sign-up-mode");
 });
 });
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.
Please do NOT include PHP if this is a client side only issue.

Comment: So, have your PHP code already set the `sign-up-mode` class on the `main` element then, when your validation of the submitted signup form data throws any errors.

Comment: In our sign-in form, one input has `name="email"name="password"`? The other input is nameless.

Comment: I am posting new question with minimal code check it out